# ajax callback function return strange data format

Tags: php, ajax

I was expecting to see the data value which a variable I set for the ajax to communicate with my php file. but this is what I get

```
Saved: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\wamp\www\ajaxExample\send.php on line <i>3</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0025</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>249728</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\ajaxExample\send.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\send.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "send.php",
  data: { item : userInput }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Saved: " + data );
  });
```

php :

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['data'];

echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: lots of _deprecated_ html tags. be careful.

Answer (score 1):

The posted data variable name isn't `data`, it's `item` so:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['item'];

?>
```